# docker php:7.1-apache don't load http_request2

Tags: php, dockerfile, http-request2

as first thing a wish to tell that I'm a noob with docker.
I'm trying to use **docker** to have a virtualized **Apache** on my machine.
This is my *dockerfile*

```
FROM php:7.1-apache
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli
RUN pecl install xdebug-2.6.0
RUN echo "VetrinaECM localhost" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
RUN pear install http_request2
RUN docker-php-ext-enable xdebug
COPY . /var/www/html/
RUN echo "xdebug.remote_enable=1" >> /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
```

and this is my *docker-compose.yml*

```
version: '2'
services:
  webserver:
    image: phpstorm/php-71-apache-xdebug-26
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
    environment:
      XDEBUG_CONFIG: remote_host=host.docker.internal
```

But when I try to import then php **http_request2** library I get this error

> Warning: require_once(HTTP/Request2.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/dadilib/get_data.php on line 4

Where am I wrong? What did I not define in the files?

Thanks

Stefano G

Comment: I don't get it, your docker-compose is using an image, not your dockerfile, and this image does not have http_request2 then. Did you mean to use this image as FROM in the dockerfile, and use build instead of image to use your own image?

Comment: Hi @ThomasDutrion, as i wrote, i don't know well docker, how work the from?
What is the right to put the from clause in the dockerfile?
Thanks

Comment: FROM in a dockerfile is the name of the image on which the following instructions should be executed. I'll answer more precisely in a proper answer now that we've established the problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to get back to docker's basic concepts a little more in depth. Not sure where you learned from, but I would recommend "That devops guy" on youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wyjNpxLRmLg&list=PLHq1uqvAteVvqQaaIAvfIWWTL_JmmXcfg

More in the PHP ecosystem, have a look at https://serversforhackers.com/t/containers

In your case, you need first to understand docker, then docker-compose.
On the docker side, you have a concept of "image", which describes how to create a "container". Think of the image as a sort of recipe, and when you docker run this image, you get a meal (a container).

In your case, you want to add pecl's http request library to `phpstorm/php-71-apache-xdebug-26`, therefore you need to execute some more instructions on top of the existing image. This is where the `Dockerfile`, `docker build` and `FROM` are in play.

```
FROM phpstorm/php-71-apache-xdebug-26

# ...
```

Once this is done, the build is done, you may run a container that has all the capabilities of the base image (from) + your customisations.

Time to get `docker-compose` on board. Docker compose is doing the orchestration part for you, meaning it will only execute many docker commands in the right sequence do avoid having to type all of the commands yourself.

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  my-first-service:
    image: phpstorm/php-71-apache-xdebug-26
  my-second-service:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

In the `docker-compose.yml` above, I am describing two services.
What docker-compose will do when doing `up` is the following:

- create a network *_default (docker network create)
- docker pull the image of my-first-service
- run a container *_my-first-service_1 (docker run)
- do a `docker build -t *_my-second-service -f Dockerfile .` (based on dockerfile and context)
- do a `docker run` of the image created.

In your case, you want to be in the same disposition as the second service, building the image first, and then running the container.

Because you created your container with an image, you only have the specifics of said image, and never called your own dockerfile.

Comment: Hi @thomas-dutrion
thanks. this wath I'm searching, if i've understood with the second service i can rebuild the image with the new extension.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround. I opened the **docker cli** and ran `pear install http_request2` from there.